# Determining the order of a Box-Jenkins modeling process

Tags: r, arima, box-jenkins

I have a problem on what model class (AR, MA, ARMA, ARIMA, etc.) will I use on my data, i.e., what order (say 1,0,1) will I use, using a Box-Jenkins procedure.

I have already done many transformations on my data but the errors are so large and the correlation is somewhat small.  My data are stationary (ADF test and KPSS test) but not normally distributed (Anderson-Darling, Wilk-Shapiro and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test). So I apply natural log and then test it again but it is still not normally distributed. So I differenced it once and it is now stationary and normally distributed.

I already satisfy the requirements of using a Box-Jenkins process. Then I use `auto.arima` in R to know what order to use and I also try SPSS using its expert modeler to cross check.

My problem is I still get large errors and small R-squared.  I need to know what to do for determining order? I also have problems in understanding ACFs and PACFs.

Below is my actual data:

```
Harvest
```

> 60477
>   29323
>   51369
>   15800
>   58994
>   45496
>   17227
>   92103
>   138573
>   39181
>   51192
>   13132
>   400
>   18258
>   54553
>   7220
>   1418
>   6807
>   17915
>   89015
>   122154
>   122853
>   63398
>   27246
>   27013
>   36317
>   65735
>   94744
>   78763
>   39769
>   20422
>   27398
>   33552
>   10000
>   6500
>   5300
>   5700
>   4800
>   5300
>   6450
>   9300
>   5834
>   29200
>   39975
>   65000
>   45494
>   79000
>   7900
>   54758
>   70581
>   31505
>   45437
>   29691
>   110947
>   40498
>   71238
>   42170
>   38723
>   64813
>   122992
>   17929
>   11652
>   134137
>   110043
>   60153
>   7625
>   25967
>   38918
>   1621
>   14946
>   76610
>   84516
>   72223
>   40399
>   63482
>   34918
>   63098
>   105388
>   135809
>   31345
>   66880
>   160511
>   40238
>   35767
>   105560
>   119276
>   154348
>   86935
>   73728
>   167119
>   128709
>   97040
>   21780
>   9906
>   62213
>   99940
>   72626
>   117783
>   58037
>   68756
>   25721
>   19853
>   4943
>   2027
>   20251
>   114718
>   27801
>   80868
>   94761
>   18914
>   119632
>   187924
>   56950
>   52886
>   141456
>   141507

[image: Harvest graph]

This is the differenced data

```
d_Harvest
```

> -31154
>   22046
>   -35569
>   43194
>   -13498
>   -28269
>   74876
>   46470
>   -99392
>   12011
>   -38060
>   -12732
>   17858
>   36295
>   -47333
>   -5802
>   5389
>   11108
>   71100
>   33139
>   699
>   -59455
>   -36152
>   -233
>   9304
>   29418
>   29009
>   -15981
>   -38994
>   -19347
>   6976
>   6154
>   -23552
>   -3500
>   -1200
>   400
>   -900
>   500
>   1150
>   2850
>   -3466
>   23366
>   10775
>   25025
>   -19506
>   33506
>   -71100
>   46858
>   15823
>   -39076
>   13932
>   -15746
>   81256
>   -70449
>   30740
>   -29068
>   -3447
>   26090
>   58179
>   -105063
>   -6277
>   122485
>   -24094
>   -49890
>   -52528
>   18342
>   12951
>   -37297
>   13325
>   61664
>   7906
>   -12293
>   -31824
>   23083
>   -28564
>   28180
>   42290
>   30421
>   -104464
>   35535
>   93631
>   -120273
>   -4471
>   69793
>   13716
>   35072
>   -67413
>   -13207
>   93391
>   -38410
>   -31669
>   -75260
>   -11874
>   52307
>   37727
>   -27314
>   45157
>   -59746
>   10719
>   -43035
>   -5868
>   -14910
>   -2916
>   18224
>   94467
>   -86917
>   53067
>   13893
>   -75847
>   100718
>   68292
>   -130974
>   -4064
>   88570
>   51

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your series of 116 weekly values is typical of many real-world series that we run into. Identification of a SARIMA model is impeded by the small sample size. The classical ARIMA model identification scheme premises no outliers, no level shifts, no seasonal dummies and no deterministic trends of the form 1,2,3,4,....t . Following is a suggested robust identification procedure which reflects the evolution of ARIMA models that incorporates deterministic structure defined here. Your series evidences a few seasonal deterministic dummies and a time trend and an ARIMA component of the form (1,0,0). The equation is [image] . There are 4 weekly indicators ; week 2 ,8 , 11 and 30 .  The acf of the errors suggests randomness in the residuals [image] and is confirmed by [image]a residual plot. Model identification of the need for the 4 seasonal dummies and the time trend was performed following the work of Tsay and others including myself as I helped develop the commercially available software that was used in this analysis.  http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf. A model summary is presented here .[image]

[image]